# Dynamic Flexbox width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Hello I'm having problems to solve this layout using css flex-box. I want to use ellipse in texts, but If I have a long content of text it push the other elements out of the box.

[image]

If I remove the display: flex of content-2-wrapper it seems to work. But I want to know if its possible to have a dynamic width of content-2-wrapper depending of the container width. And use with this the ellipsis in texts.

I add the code:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: magenta;
  
}

.d-flex {
  display: flex;
  padding: 16px;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.content-1 {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 16px;
}

.content-2-wrapper {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content-2a {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 16px;
}

.content-2b {
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 16px;
}

.content-3 {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 16px;
}

.content-4 {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 16px;
}

.ellipsis {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="d-flex">
    <div class="content-1">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="content-2-wrapper">
      <div class="content-2a ellipsis">
        Very long content that breake my flex layout
      </div>
      <div class="content-2b ellipsis">
        second-content
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-3 ellipsis">
      another content
    </div>
    <div class="content-4 ellipsis">
      last content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's just two things you need to do:

- Set `min-width: [something]` on the immediate flex children. If you don't set a value, `auto` is used by default.
- Set `box-sizing: border-box` on `.d-flex` and any other element that has a width/min-width *and* defined padding.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: magenta;
  
}

.d-flex {
  display: flex;
  padding: 16px;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content-1 {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 16px;
  min-width: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content-2-wrapper {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 25%;
}

.content-2a {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 16px;
}

.content-2b {
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 16px;
}

.content-3 {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 16px;
  min-width: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content-4 {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 16px;
  min-width: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ellipsis {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="d-flex">
    <div class="content-1">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="content-2-wrapper">
      <div class="content-2a ellipsis">
        Very long content that breake my flex layout
      </div>
      <div class="content-2b ellipsis">
        second-content
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-3 ellipsis">
      another content
    </div>
    <div class="content-4 ellipsis">
      last content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```